# How do i convert the units to frames per seconds as speed?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this in form1 i assign to label2 the timer interval the default interval is 100ms.
I want that the user will see it and change the interval speed as frames per second:

```
label2.Text = timer1.Interval.ToString();
```

And this is the mouse wheel event in Form1:

```
private void Form1_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            PbsWheel pbsw = new PbsWheel(pbs, pb, e.Delta, label2);
        }
```

And this is the class Pbswheel 
pbs is array of pictureBoxes and pb is a pictureBox.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WeatherMaps
{
    class PbsWheel
    {
        public PbsWheel(AnimatedPictureBox.AnimatedPictureBoxs[] pbs, AnimatedPictureBox.AnimatedPictureBoxs pb, int delta,Label label2)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < pbs.Length; i++)
            {

                if (delta > 0)
                {
                    if (pbs[i].AnimateRate < 5000)
                    {
                        if (pbs[i].AnimateRate < 1000)
                        {
                            pbs[i].AnimateRate += 100;
                            label2.Text = (pbs[i].AnimateRate / (double)1000).ToString();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            pbs[i].AnimateRate += 1000;
                            label2.Text = (pbs[i].AnimateRate / 1000).ToString();
                        }
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    if (pbs[i].AnimateRate > 1000)
                    {
                        pbs[i].AnimateRate -= 1000;
                        label2.Text = (pbs[i].AnimateRate / 1000).ToString();
                    }

                    else

                        if (pbs[i].AnimateRate <= 1000 && pbs[i].AnimateRate > 100)
                        {
                            pbs[i].AnimateRate -= 100;
                            label2.Text = (pbs[i].AnimateRate / (double)1000).ToString();
                        }
                }
            }

            if (delta > 0)
            {
                if (pb.AnimateRate < 5000)
                {
                    if (pb.AnimateRate < 1000)
                    {
                        pb.AnimateRate += 100;
                        label2.Text = (pb.AnimateRate / (double)1000).ToString();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        pb.AnimateRate += 1000;
                        label2.Text = (pb.AnimateRate / 1000).ToString();
                    }
                }

            }
            else
            {
                if (pb.AnimateRate > 1000)
                {
                    pb.AnimateRate -= 1000;
                    label2.Text = (pb.AnimateRate / 1000).ToString();
                }

                else

                    if (pb.AnimateRate <= 1000 && pb.AnimateRate > 100)
                    {
                        pb.AnimateRate -= 100;
                        label2.Text = (pb.AnimateRate / (double)1000).ToString();
                    }
            }        
        }
    }
}
```

what it does now when im running the program i see on label2 100(100ms)
Then when i move the wheel down its going to minimum 0.1 the fastest.
When i move it up its move : 01,0.2,0.3....0.9,1,2,3,4,5
Maximum speed 5 seconds.

What it does is changing the speed the images in each pictureBox will be shown as animation/loop.

The AnimateRate is in this class im using this class to make a timer for each pictureBox for the animation/loop of images and the AnimateRate is setting the speed when im moving the mouse wheel.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using DannyGeneral;

namespace WeatherMaps
{
    class AnimatedPictureBox
    {
        //Use this custom PictureBox for convenience
        public class AnimatedPictureBoxs : PictureBox
        {
            public static bool images; 
            List<string> imageFilenames;
            Timer t = new Timer();
            public AnimatedPictureBoxs()
            {
                images = false;
                AnimateRate = 100; //It's up to you, the smaller, the faster.
                t.Tick += Tick_Animate;
            }
            public int AnimateRate
            {
                get { return t.Interval; }
                set { t.Interval = value; }
            }
            public void Animate(List<string> imageFilenames)
            {
                this.imageFilenames = imageFilenames;
                t.Start();
            }
            public void StopAnimate()
            {
                t.Stop();
                i = 0;
            }
            int i;
            private void Tick_Animate(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (images == true)
                {
                    imageFilenames = null;
                }
                if (imageFilenames == null)
                {
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (i >= imageFilenames.Count)
                        {
                            i = 0;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Load(imageFilenames[i]);
                            i = (i + 1) % imageFilenames.Count;
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception err)
                    {
                        Logger.Write(err.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

timer1 in form1 is never use i just did that label2 text will be the timer1 default interval but im not using the timer1.

The code is bit long but its all connected.

Instead changing the speed as it is now i want to change it as frames per second units.

Answer (score 1):

Frames per second is a *frequency*, f,  and interval is a *period*, P. The relationship between frequencies and periods is

```
P = 1/f
```

I think that is all you need to know.